# Create an image every time I click a button JS

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to create one image each time I click on a button and I will need to be able to drag this each image to move it where I want.
At this moment my code works only for one image.

I think I need to create my div in JS but this doesn't work..

```js
const CreerPerso = document.getElementById('createPerso');

CreerPerso.onclick = CreationPersonnage;


async function CreationPersonnage() {
  /*var divImg = document.createElement('div');
  divImg.setAttribute("id", "imgPerso");
  document.getElementById('body').appendChild(divImg);*/
  document.getElementById("imgPerso").innerHTML = "<img src='images/circle.png' />";


  //drag images Personnage
  dragElement(document.getElementById("imgPerso"));

  function dragElement(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0,
      pos2 = 0,
      pos3 = 0,
      pos4 = 0;
    if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id)) {
      // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
      document.getElementById(elmnt.id).onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    } else {
      // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
      elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
      document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
      // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
      document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      // calculate the new cursor position:
      pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
      pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
      // set the element's new position:
      elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
      elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
      // stop moving when mouse button is released:
      document.onmouseup = null;
      document.onmousemove = null;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body id="body">

  <button id="createPerso" class="btn btn-primary">Créer Personnage</button>
  <div id="imgPerso">

  </div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No need for async
2. No need to give body an ID
3. You pass the element, no need to get the ID to get the element
4. IDs need to be unique

This is simpler

```js
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  elmnt.dataset.pos1 = 0,
    elmnt.dataset.pos2 = 0,
    elmnt.dataset.pos3 = 0,
    elmnt.dataset.pos4 = 0;
  // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
  elmnt.addEventListener("mousedown", dragMouseDown);
}

function dragMouseDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const elemt = e.target;
  // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
  elemt.dataset.pos3 = e.clientX;
  elemt.dataset.pos4 = e.clientY;
}

function elementDrag(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const elemt = e.target;
  if (elemt) {
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    let pos1 = elemt.dataset.pos3 - elemt.clientX;
    let pos2 = elemt.dataset.pos4 - elemt.clientY;
    let = elemt.clientX;
    let = elemt.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elemt.style.top = (elemt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elemt.style.left = (elemt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }
}

function closeDragElement() {
  // stop moving when mouse button is released:
  document.onmouseup = null;
  document.onmousemove = null;
}

const CreerPerso = document.getElementById('createPerso');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
CreerPerso.addEventListener("click", CreationPersonnage);


function CreationPersonnage() {
  const divImg = document.createElement('div');
  divImg.classList.add("imgPerso");

  divImg.innerHTML = "<img src='images/circle.png' />";
  body.appendChild(divImg);

  //drag images Personnage
  dragElement(divImg);

}

document.addEventListener("mouseup", closeDragElement);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", elementDrag);
```

```css
.imgPerso {
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<button id="createPerso" class="btn btn-primary">Créer Personnage</button>
```

Comment: Thaks mplungjan It solved one of the problem but now I can't drag the images

Comment: I added more code, but do not have time to fix the drag. You need to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Id's in HTML need to be unique, so you should add a counter or something to the div you create and keep that id for future reference.

```
var personImageIdCount = 0;
async function CreationPersonnage() {
  var personImageId = "imgPerso_" + (personImageIdCount++).toString();
  var divImg = document.createElement('div');
  divImg.setAttribute("id", personImageId);
  document.getElementById('body').appendChild(divImg);
```